# Game programming - How to avoid reinventing the wheel

Tags: frameworks

Summary:

> **Can I program a "thick
>   client" game in C without reinventing
>   wheels**, or should I just bite the
>   bullet and use some library or SDK?
>   I'm a moderate C programmer and am not
>   afraid to work with pointers, data
>   structures, memory locations, etc. if
>   it will give me the control I need to
>   make a great "thick-client" game. 
>   However, I'm thinking of eschewing
>   high-level languages & frameworks for
>   the sake of power and control, *not*
>   ease of use.

I'm interesting in tinkering with a 2D fighting/platforming game as a side project sometime.  I'm primarily a Linux server-side programmer with experience in Python, Ruby and PHP.  I know that there are excellent frameworks in some of these languages, like [PyGame](http://www.pygame.org/news.html).  I am also aware of the success people have had with stuff like Air and .NET... but I have some concerns:

- **Performance**: Scripting languages are notoriously slow.  If I'm making a real-time game, I want it to be as snappy as possible.
- **Huge binaries**: Using frameworks like .NET or scripting languages like Ruby often result in big CLRs or libraries that you wouldn't otherwise need.  The game I want to make will be small and simple--I don't want its CLR to be bigger than the game itself!
- **Extra stuff**: Honestly, I just don't like the idea of inheriting some big game library's baggage if I can wrap my head around my own code better.

I'm asking this question because I know I'm very susceptible to Not Invented Here Syndrome.  I always want to program it myself, and I'm sure it wastes a lot of time.  However, this works out for me remarkably often--for example, instead of using [Rails](http://www.rubyonrails.org/) (a very big web project framework with an ORM and GUI toolkit baked in), I used an array of smaller Ruby tools like [rack](http://rack.rubyforge.org/) and [sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/) that fit together beautifully.

So, I turn to you, SO experts.  Am I being naive?  Here's how I see it:

- **Use C**

  - **Cons**

    - Will probably make me hate programming
    - High risk of reinventing wheels
    - High risk of it taking so long that I lose interest
  - **Pros**

    - Tried & true - most A-list games are done in C (is this still true today?)
    - High level of control over memory management, speed, asset management, etc., which I trust myself to learn to handle
    - No cruft
- **Use framework or SDK**

  - **Cons**

    - Risk of oversized deliverable
    - Dependent on original library authors for all facets of game development--what if there isn't a feature I want?  I'll have to program it myself, which isn't bad, but partially defeats the purpose of using a high-level framework in the first place
    - High risk of performance issues
  - **Pros**

    - MUCH faster development time
    - Might be easier to maintain
    - No time wasted reinventing common paradigms

What else can I add to this list?  Is it a pure judgment call, or can someone seal the deal for me?  Book suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My current thinking is:

- If you want to learn to program, start making the game engine from the base elements upwards (even implementing basic data structures - lists, maps, etc). I've done this once, and while it was a learning experience, I made many mistakes, and I wouldn't do this a second time around. However for learning how to program as well as making something cool and seeing results I'd rate this highly.
- If you want to make a proper game, use whatever libraries that you want and design all of the game infrastructure yourself. This is what I'm doing now, and I'm using all of the nice things like STL, ATL/WTL, Boost, SQLite, DirectX, etc. So far I've learnt a lot about the middle/game logic aspect of the code and design.
- If you just want to make a game with artists and other people collaborating to create a finished product, use one of the existing engines (OGRE, Irrlicht, Nebula, Torque, etc) and just add in your game logic and art.

One final bit of wisdom I've learnt is that don't worry about the Not Invented Here syndrome. As I've come to realise that other libraries (such as STL, Boost, DirectX, etc) have an order of magnitude (or three) more man-hours of development time in them, far more than I could ever spend on that portion of the game/engine. Therefore the only reason to implement these things yourself is if you want to learn about them.

Comment: Can we make a graphical game using only C and no other libraries?

Answer (score 13):

I believe you are working under a fallacy.

There are several frameworks out there specifically for game programming --- written by people with much experience with the complication of game design, almost certainly more tha you do.

In other words, you have a "High risk of performance issues" if you DON'T use a framework.

Answer (score 7):

I would recomend you try [pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/).

- It has good performance, as it utilizes opengl
- Its a compact all-in-one library
- It has no extra dependencies besides python

Do some tests, see if you can make it fast enough for you. Only if you prove to yourself that it's not move to a lower level. Although, I'm fairly confident that python + pyglet can handle it... at worst you'll have to write a few C extensions.

Answer (score 4):

Today, I believe you are at a point where you can safely ignore the performance issue unless you're specifically trying to do something that pushes the limits.  If your game is, say, no more complicated than Quake II, then you should choose tools and libraries that let you do the most for **your** time.

Why did I choose Quake II?  Because running in [a version compiled for .NET](http://www.vertigosoftware.com/Quake2.htm), it runs with a software renderer at a more than acceptable frame rate on a current machine.  (If you like - compare MAME which emulates multiple processors and graphics hardware at acceptable rates)

Answer (score 4):

You need to ask yourself if you are in this to build an engine or to build a game.  If your purpose is to create a game, you should definitely look at an established gaming engine.  For 2D game development, look at [Torque Game Builder](http://www.garagegames.com/products/torque/tgb/).  It is a very powerful 2D gaming engine/SDK that will put you into production from day 1.  They have plenty of tools that integrate with it, content packs, and you get the full source code if you want to make changes and/or learn how it works.  It is also Mac OSX compatible and has Linux versions in the community.

If you are looking for something on the console side, they have that too.

Answer (score 4):

I'm surprised nobody has mentioned [XNA](http://www.xna.com/).  Its a framework built around DirectX for doing managed DirectX programming while removing a lot of the fluff and verbosity of lower level DirectX programming.

Performance-wise, for most 2D and 3D game tasks, especially building something like a fighting game, this platform works very well.  Its not *as* fast as if you were doing bare metal DirectX programming, but it gets you very close, and in a managed environment, no less.

Another cool benefit of XNA is that most of the code can be run on an Xbox 360 and can even be debugged over the network connection was the game runs on the Xbox.  XNA games are now allowed to be approved by the Xbox Live team for distribution and sale on Xbox Live Arcade as well.  So if you're looking to take the project to a commercial state, you might have am available means of distribution at your disposal.

Like all MS development tools, the documentation and support is first rate, and there is a large developer community with plenty of tutorials, existing projects, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to be able to play your game on a console?  Do you want to do it as a learning experience?  Do you want the final product to be cross platform?  Which libraries have you looked into so far?

For a 2d game I don't think performance will be a problem, I recommend going with something that will get you results on screen in the shortest amount of time.  If you have a lot of experience doing Python then pyGame is a good choice.

If you plan on doing some 3d games in the future, I would recommend taking a look at Ogre (http://www.ogre3d.org).  It's a cross platform 3d graphics engine that abstracts away the graphics APIs.  However for a 2d project it's probably overkill.

Answer (score 2):

The most common implementation language for A-list games today is C++, and a lot of games embed a scripting language (such as Python or Lua) for game event scripting.

The tools you'd use to write a game have a lot to do with your reasons for writing it, and with your requirements. This is no different from any other programming project, really. If it's a side project, and you're doing it on your own, then only you can assess how much time you have to spend on this and what your performance requirements are.

Generally speaking, today's PCs are fast enough to run 2D platformers written in scripting languages. Using a scripting language will allow you to prototype things faster and you'll have more time to tweak the gameplay. Again, this is no different than with any other project.

If you go with C++, and your reasons don't have to be more elaborate than "because I want to," I would suggest that you look at SDL for rendering and audio support. It will make things a little bit easier.

If you want to learn the underlying technologies (DirectX, or you want to write optimized blitters for some perverse reason) then by all means, use C++.

Having said all that, I would caution you against premature optimization. For a 2D game, you'll probably be better off going with Python and PyGame first. I'd be surprised if those tools will prove to be inadequate on modern PCs.

Answer (score 2):

As to what people have said about C/C++/Python, I'm a game developer and my company encourages C. Not b/c C++ is bad, but because badly written C++ is poison for game development due to it's difficulty to read/debug compared to C. (C++ gives benefits when used properly, but let a junior guy make some mistakes with it and your time sink is huge)

As to the actual question:
If your purpose is to just get something working, use a library.

Otherwise, code it yourself for a very important reason: *Practice*

Practice in manipulating data structures. There WILL be times you need to manage your own data. Practice in debugging utility code.

Often libs do just what you want and are great, but sometimes *YOUR* specific use case is handled very badly by the lib and you will gain big benefits from writing you own. This is especially on consoles compared to PCs

(edit:) Regarding script and garbage collection: it *will* kill you on a console, on a recent game I had to rewrite major portions of the garbage collection on Unreal just to fill our needs in the *editor* portion. Even more had to be done in the actual game (not just by me)  (to be fair though we were pushing beyond Unreal's original specs)

Scripting often good, but it is not an "I win" button.  In general the gains disappear if you are pushing against the limits of your platform. I would use "percent of platforms CPU that I have to spare" as my evaluation function in deciding how appropriate script is

Answer (score 2):

One consideration in favor of C/C++/obj-C is that you can mix and match various libraries for different areas of concern.  In other words, you are not stuck with the implementation of a feature in a framework.

I use this approach in [my games](http://physle.com); using [chipmunk](http://wiki.slembcke.net/main/published/Chipmunk) for 2D physics, Lua as an embedded scripting language, and an openGL ES implementation from Apple. I write the glue to tie all of these together in a C language.  The final product being the ability to define game objects, create instances of them, and handle events as they interact with each other in C functions exposed to Lua.  This approach is used in [many high performance games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_(programming_language)#Games) to much success.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't already know C++, I would definitely recommend you go forward with a scripting language.  Making a game from start to finish takes a lot of motivation, and forcing yourself to learn a new language at the same time is a good way to make things go slowly enough that you lose interest (although it IS a good way to learn a new language...).

Most scripting languages will be compiled to byte code anyway, so their biggest performance hit will be the garbage collection.  I'm not experienced enough to give a definite description of how big a hit garbage collection would be, but I would be inclined to think that it shouldn't be too bad in a small game.

Also, if you use an existing scripting language library to make your game, most of the performance critical areas (like graphics) can be written in C++ anyway (hopefully by the game libraries).  So 80% of the CPU might actually be spent in C++ code anyway, despite the fact that most of your project is written in, say Python.

I would say, ask yourself what you want more: To write a game from start to finish and learn about game development, or to learn a new language (C++).  If you want to write a game, do it in a scripting language.  If you want to learn a new language, do it in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah unless you just want to learn all of the details of the things that go into making a game, you definitely want to go with a game engine and just focus on building your game logic rather than the details of graphics, audio, resource management, etc.

Personally I like to recommend the Torque Game Builder (aka Torque 2D) from [GarageGames](http://www.garagegames.com). But you can probably find some free game engines out there that will suit your needs as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure most modern games are done in C++, not C. (Every gaming company I ever interviewed with asked C++ questions.)
Why not use C++ and existing libraries for physics + collisions, sound, graphics engine etc. You still write the game, but the mundane stuff is taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

There are alot of different solutions to the issue of abstracting and each deals with it in different ways.

My current project uses C#, DirectX 9, HLSL and SlimDX. Each of these offers a carefully calibrated level of abstraction. HLSL allows me to actually read the shader code I'm writing and SlimDX/C# allows me to ignore pointers, circular dependencies and handling unmanaged code.

That said, none of these technologies has any impact on the ease of developing my AI, lighting or physics! I still have to break out my textbooks in a way that I wouldn't with a higher-level framework.

Even using a framework like XNA, if most video games development concepts are foreign to you there's a hell of a lot still to take in and learn. XNA will allow you to neatly sidestep gimbal lock, but woe betide those who don't understand basic shading concepts. On the other hand, something like DarkBASIC won't solve your gimbal lock problem, but shading is mostly handled for you.

It's a sufficiently big field that your first engine will never be the one you actually use. If you write it yourself, you won't write it well enough. If you use third party libraries, there's certainly aspects that will annoy you and you'll want to replace.

As an idea, it might be worth taking various libraries/frameworks (definately make XNA one of your stops, even if you decide you don't want to use it, it's a great benchmark) and trying to build various prototypes. Perhaps a landscape (with a body of water) or a space physics demo.