# Learning about low-level graphics programming

Tags: graphics

I'm interesting in learning about the different layers of abstraction available for making graphical applications.

I see a lot of terms thrown around:  At the highest level of abstraction, I hear about things like C#, .NET, pyglet and pygame.  Further down, I hear about DirectX and OpenGL.  Then there's DirectDraw, SDL, the Win32 API, and still other multi-platform libraries like WxWidgets.

How can I get a good sense of where one of these layers ends and where the next one begins?  What is the "lowest possible level" way of creating a window in Windows, in C?  What about C++?  (A code sample would be divine.)  What about in X11?  Are the Windows implementations of OpenGL and DirectX built on top of the Win32 API?  Where can I begin to learn about these things?

There's another question on SO where [Programming Windows](http://www.charlespetzold.com/pw5/) is suggested.  What about for Linux?  Is there an equivalent such book?

I'm aware that this is very low-level, and that there are many friendlier tools available, but I would like to at least learn the basics of what's going on beneath the surface.  As much as I'd like to begin slinging windows and vectors right off the bat, starting with something like pygame is too high-level for me; I really need to make the full conceptual circuit of *how you draw stuff on a computer*.

I will certainly appreciate suggestions for books and resources, but I think it would be stupendously cool if the answers to this question filled up with lots of different ways to get to "Hello world" with different approaches to graphics programming.  C?  C++?  Using OpenGL?  Using DirectX?  On Windows XP?  On Ubuntu?  Maybe I ask for too much.

Comment: "What about for Linux? Is there an equivalent such book?" - There is one now - http://www.amazon.com/The-Linux-Programming-Interface-Handbook/dp/1593272200 - very rarely does a book have a 100% 5-star rating, and 39 is a reasonably good sample size.

Comment: Max , i got the same question , i just want to know have you find your way through all your questions , because these same questions bugs me too

Comment: @SurajJain, it's not much, but there are a couple of other questions I've asked that could get you started too:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235151/game-programming-how-to-avoid-reinventing-the-wheel

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850071/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-render-a-3d-cube-with-a-single-lighting-source

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[Michael Abrash's Graphics Programming 'Black Book'](http://www.drdobbs.com/high-performance-computing/184404919) is a great place to start. Plus you can download it for free!

Comment: Available at http://www.drdobbs.com/high-performance-computing/184404919 (for now :) ).

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, I have a feeling this will be a huge help.

Comment: Is it for beginner ?

Answer (score 48):

The lowest level would be the graphics card's video RAM. When the computer first starts, the graphics card is typically set to the 80x25 character legacy mode.

You can write text with a BIOS provided interrupt at this point. You can also change the foreground and background color from a palette of 16 distinctive colors. You can use access ports/registers to change the display mode. At this point you could say, load a different font into the display memory and still use the 80x25 mode (OS installations usually do this) or you can go ahead and enable VGA/SVGA. It's quite complicated, that's what drivers are for.

Once the card's in the 'higher' mode you'd change what's on screen by accessing the memory mapped to the video card. It's stored horizontally pixel by pixel with some 'dirty regions' of pixels that aren't mapped to screen at the end of each line which you have to compensate for. But yeah, you could copy the pixels of an image in memory directly to the screen.

For things like DirectX, OpenGL. rather than write directly to the screen, commands are sent to the graphics card and it updates its screen automatically. Commands like "Hey you, draw this image I've loaded into the VRAM here, here and here" or "Draw these triangles with this transformation matrix..." take a fraction of the time compared to pixel by pixel . The CPU will thank you.

DirectX/OpenGL is a programmer friendly library for sending those commands to the card with all the supporting functions to help you get it done smoothly. A more direct approach  would only be unproductive.

SDL is an abstraction layer so without bothering to read up on it I'd guess it would have different ways of working on each system. On one it might use semi-direct screen writing, another Direct3D, etc. Whatever's fastest as long as the code stays cross-platform..able.

The GDI/GDI+ and XWindow system. They're designed specifically to draw windows. Originally they drew using the pixel-by-pixel method (which was good enough because they'd only have to redraw when a button was pressed or a window moved, etc.) but now they use Direct3D/OpenGL for accelerated drawing (and special effects). Optimizations depend on the versions and implementations of these libraries.

So if you want the most power and speed, DirectX/openGL is the way to go. SDL is certainly useful for getting the most from a cross-platform environment and integrates with OpenGL anyway. The windowing system comes last but don't underestimate it. Especially with the stuff Microsoft's coming up with lately.

Comment: Heh, heh, Na, the lowest level is VHDL or Verilog design of a VGA controller!  Actually check this out http://neil.franklin.ch/Projects/SoftVGA/ That's just using a micro controller!

Answer (score 6):

If you really want to start at the bottom then drawing a line is the most basic operation.    Computer graphics is simply about filling in pixels on a grid (screen), so you need to work out which pixels to fill in to get a line that goes from (x0,y0) to (x1,y1).

Check out [Bresenham's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenhams_line_algorithm) to get a feel for what is involved.

Comment: If a line is drawn by filling pixels on a grid, how can drawing a line be more basic than ... setting a pixel? :)

Answer (score 6):

To be a good graphics and image processing programmer doesn't require this low level knowledge, but i do hate to be clueless about the insides of what i'm using.  I see two ways to chase this - high-level down, or bottom-level up.

Top-down is a matter of following how the action traces from a high-level graphics operation  such as to draw a circle, to the hardware.  Get to know OpenGL well.  Then the source to Mesa (free!) provides a peek at how OpenGL can be implemented in software.   The source to Xorg would be next, first to see how the action goes from API calls through the client side to the X server.  Finally you dive into a device driver that interfaces with hardware.

Bottom up:  build your own graphics hardware.  Think of ways it could connect to a computer - how to handle massive numbers of pixels through a few byte-size registers, how DMA would work.  Write a device driver, and try designing a graphics library that might be useful for app programmers.

The bottom-up way is how i learned, years ago when it was a possibility with the slow 8-bit microprocessors.  The direct experience with circuitry and hardware-software interfacing gave me a good appreciation of the difficult design decisions - e.g. to  paint rectangles using clever hardware, in the device driver, or higher level.   None of this is of practical everyday value, but provided a foundation of knowledge to understand newer technology.

Comment: Sir , i have a question That i wanted to ask for so long , does c without including any graphic library have function that could make me something like a circle , or more basic thing , manipulate a pixel , it does not matter how long is the code?

Comment: @SurajJain maybe you can find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32972051/in-c-how-do-i-write-to-a-particular-memory-location-e-g-video-memory-b800-in    from my understanding, if you could access VRAM (It's like normal RAM but the hardware that does graphics uses it to store pixel values, I think) using pure c then if you change the value of anything in VRAM you should see a pixel somewhere change color.

Answer (score 4):

see Open GPU Documentation section:
http://developer.amd.com/documentation/guides/Pages/default.aspx

HTH

Answer (score 3):

On MSWindows it is easy: you use what the API provides, whether it is the standard **windows programming API** or the **DirectX-family API's**: that's what you use, and they are well documented.

In an X windows environment you use whatever **X11-libraries** that are provided. If you want to understand the principles behind windowing on X, I suggest that you do this, nevermind that many others tell you not to, it will really help you to understand graphics and windowing under X. You can read the documentation on X-programming (google for it). (After this exercise you would appreciate the higher level libraries!)

Apart from the above, at the absolutely lowest level (excluding chip-level) that you can go is to call the interrupts that switch to the various graphics modes available - there are several -  and then write to the screen buffers, but for this you would have to use assembler, anything else would be too slow. Going this way will not be portable at all.

Another post mentions **Abrash's Black Book** - an excellent resource.

Edit: As for books on programming Linux: it is a community thing, there are many howto's around; also find a forum, join it, and as long as you act civilized you will get all the help you can ever need.

Answer (score 2):

Right off the bat, I'd say "you're asking too much."  From what little experience I've had, I would recommend reading some tutorials or getting a book on either directX or OpenGL to start out.  To go any lower than that would be pretty complex.  Most of the books I've seen in OGL or DX have pretty good introductions that explain what the functions/classes do.

Once you get the hang of one of these, you could always dig in to the libraries to see what exactly they're doing to go lower.

Or, if you really, absolutely MUST learn the LOWEST level... read the book in the above post.

Answer (score 2):

libX11 is the lowest level library for X11. I believe the opengl/directx talk to the driver/hardware directly (or emulate unsupported ops), so they would be the lowest level library.

If you want to start with *very* low level programming, look for x86 assembly code for VGA and fire up a copy of dosbox or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Vulkan api is an api which gives you very low level access to most if not all features of the gpu, computational and graphical, it works on amd and Nvidia gpus (not all)

you can also use CUDA, but it only works on Nvidia gpus and has access to computational features only, no video output.