# What is the simplest way to render a 3D cube with a single lighting source?

Tags: c, opengl, graphics, 3d

Depicted below is a crappy Photoshop mockup of a three-dimensional cube.

[image: a crappy 3D cube]

Here are my parameters: The solution must...

- ... compile and run on my dinky but faithful Macbook Air *without* using Windows emulators like wine
- ... produce a window that looks reasonably close to the above mockup when run
- ... use only free tools ("free" as in "speech" *and* "beer")
- ... use C (not C++ or C#)
- ... be capable of rendering the cube viewed from different angles defined at compile-time, perhaps with preprocessor macros
- ... make use of the GPU

Weee!

Potential resources:

- http://www.gamedev.net/topic/579689-sdl--opengl-rendering-a-cube/
- http://www.evl.uic.edu/arao/cs594/sdlglsl.html

Comment: This is covered by almost every OpenGL tutorial on the planet... http://www.google.com/search?q=opengl+tutorial

Comment: @DietrichEpp - Your input is appreciated! But, if Googling "opengl tutorial" had been enough for me to immediately start seeing results, I wouldn't have bothered posting this question.

Comment: The first link I get is to NeHe, and the legacy tutorials walk you through making a cube by lesson 5.  And they have OS X code available.

Comment: I did stumble on those tutorials before; see the comment thread in Mark Stevens' answer for how that panned out...

Comment: So using Cocoa is unacceptable?  Then use SDL or GLUT.  Both work fine on OS X.  Source code still available from NeHe, but you may need to tweak the build system for OS X.  (Why is Cocoa not acceptable?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NeHe tutorials are outdated and do not compile, so I wrote [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mcantor/10995685) to answer my own question with a working snippet that obeys all the parameters of my question.

It can be compiled on OS X 10.9.2 like so:

`$ gcc -Wall -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT -o my3dcube my3dcube.c`

It is adapted heavily from the code in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/10995796) and the NeHe tutorials linked to in Mark Stevens' answer.

Answer (score 3):

I would go to Nehe tutorials, 1-5. By the #5 you'll be rendering the above cube in OpenGL.

The tutorials are straight C, but they have links to ports at the bottom of the page for just about every language you might want to use.

[Nehe OpenGL](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/lessons_01__05/22004/)

Comment: Thanks, looks like this might be perfect. I kept seeing people talk about "nehe" everywhere, but I was ignoring the tutorial links because they put them under the "Legacy" heading. Guess I should have been more adventurous!

Comment: Hmm... looks like this tutorial assumes you are using Visual C++ on Windows, meaning it may fail the parameters of my question. I'll keep reading and see how far down the rabbit hole goes when using OS X and C instead.

Comment: Yes, they are *legacy* in the sense that they don't use modern shader technology. But they still work just fine and satisfy your requirements. After the "cube", you probably want to have a look at shaders, but you'll need a complete OpenGL C program anyway to host the shader.

Comment: The tutorial walks you thru VC++, but at the bottom there are links to ports for pretty much every other compiler/OS - including 2 different MAC versions.

Comment: Looks like the links to the non-Cocoa Mac ports are all broken. Lame!

Comment: Ahhh, sorry. I guess maybe that's what they *really* mean by 'legacy'.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to start with OpenGL. It's the only thing that fits that bill entirely. That being said, if you've never written C code before... it's going to be a heavy start.

I'd start by visiting [This site](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c-tutorial.html) and learning C before you do anything with OpenGL and graphics.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer in my question: I already know C, and in fact I've worked with SDL before. I'm adding this question to StackOverflow because I didn't see a good existing example here; even if the best answer is just a link to a really solid tutorial, it'll be nice for SO to cover a bit more ground that way.